# jQuery: return string as html

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a "Label" control on my form which is being populated via jquery.  My problem however, is I need to return my string with html tags, but my label doesn't seem to recognize html.  Here's my control:

```
<label id="comment"></label>
```

And here's how I'm working with it in javascript:

```
var comment;
comment = $("#comment");
comment.text("<b>Please scan an <br/>item!</b>");
```

In the above code, the html in my string is ignored.  Is there any way I can get my form to recognize the returned html tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function :

```
comment.html("<b>Please scan an <br/>item!</b>");
```

Comment: Specifically, the [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function deliberately escapes the string so it renders correctly in html. As a result, things like <b> get converted to &lt;b&gt;

Answer (score 3):

try `comment.html("<b>Please scan an <br/>item!</b>");`

You could also use `document.getElementById("comment").innerHTML = "<b>Please scan an <br/>item!</b>";`

Answer (score 0):

```
comment.html("<b>Please scan an <br/>item!</b>");
```

Comment: It's the same problem as the question!